# My output keeps on repeating itself? (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop

so i'm creating this function that gets a user to input a number greater than 2.
The code should then print all the prime numbers starting from 2 and ending at the number the user inputted.

So here is my code and it works (yay!)

```
def enterNumber():
    
    number = int(input("Enter a number greater than 2"))
    
    lower = 2
    upper = number

    for number in range (lower, upper):
        if number > 2:
            for i in range (2, number):
                if (number % i) == 0:
                    break
            
                else:
                   if (number % i) != 0:
                       print(number)
                
enterNumber()
```

BUT here is my output if the user inputs 18

```
"Enter a number greater than 2"  
 user puts "18"

output: 3
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
9
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
15
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
```

why is my output repeating itself? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: You could walk through you code, line by line, including all the loops, e.g. with the number 5.  This way you can find this kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for i in range (2, number):
    if (number % i) == 0:
        break
    
    else:
        if (number % i) != 0:
            print(number)
```

The `else` being *inside* the loop, says that you're going to print the number *every* time you find a non-divisor.  For instance, for number = 11, you will print `11` for `i` values 2-10.

You don't know whether the number is a prime until you are *done* with the loop.  Your print has to go after the loop, on a normal exit.  An often-forgotten language feature is that a loop can have an `else` for exactly this purpose.

```
        for i in range (2, number):
            if (number % i) == 0:
                break
            
        else:
            print(number)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number greater than 218
3
5
7
11
13
17
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution(there are better ways):

```
def enterNumber():
    number = int(input("Enter a number greater than 2"))

    lower = 2
    upper = number

    for number in range(lower, upper):
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, number):
            if (number % i) == 0:
                prime = False
                break

        if prime:
            print(number)


enterNumber()
```